# Button click to remove the advertisement after navigating to another page

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an ad and a button to remove this same ad on my main page (I only have advertising on the main page), in a uwp app. If I click the button it removes the ad and the button, but if I navigate to another page (for example settings) and go back again to the main page the ad and the button to remove is already there again.

In my XAML I have both elements (button and advertising) appear as: `Visibility="Visible"`

This is my code to remove the ad:

```
private async void removeAds_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!AppLicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["RemoveAdsOffer"].IsActive)
            {
                try
                {
                    PurchaseResults results = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("RemoveAdsOffer");

                    if (results.Status == ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded)
                    {
                        removeAds.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        Ad.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want remove the Button and Ad, when you go back to the main page?

Comment: Yes. When I click in the button to remove the ad `removeAds_Click`, this remove the button and the ad, but if I navigate for another page, and after back to main page the button and the ad is already there again (dont dissappear)